# Is there some approaches that will log information in the last row for specific columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google sheets, I tried to log some information I entered in other sheet to my invoiceLogSheet.
but the problem is : when the information log to the sheet, it always log in the last row for entire sheet, and what I want is : to log in last row for specific range of columns
(clarify more: to check in specific columns their free last row and log the information on this row)

but I don't know how to script this .. this is the function I used and it does not do the job I want:

```
function InvoiceLog(invoice_number, part, due_date, totalInvoice, payable_to, project_name, note)
{
  
   //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE INVOICE LOG SHEET          
  var invoiceLogSheet = ss.getSheetByName("information"); 
  
  
  //GET LAST ROW OF INVOICE LOG SHEET
  var nextRowInvoice = invoiceLogSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  
 
  
  //POPULATE INVOICE LOG
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(nextRowInvoice, 2).setValue(invoice_number);
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(nextRowInvoice, 3).setValue(part);  
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(nextRowInvoice, 4).setValue(due_date);
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(nextRowInvoice, 5).setValue(totalInvoice);
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(nextRowInvoice, 6).setValue(payable_to);
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(nextRowInvoice, 7).setValue(project_name);
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(nextRowInvoice, 8).setValue(note);


}
```

the columns I want to check the last row in them is (B:H).

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

One way to approach this problem is to use the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632165/determining-the-last-row-in-a-single-column) question.

Essentially for each of the selected columns you calculate the total number of rows like that:

`invoiceLogSheet.getRange('B:B').getValues().filter(String).length +1`

Please note that this approach will give you the total number of non empty cells in a particular column. If you have blank cells, then it will give you a smaller number than the correct one.

### Solution:

```
function InvoiceLog(invoice_number, part, due_date, totalInvoice, payable_to, project_name, note)
{
  
   //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE INVOICE LOG SHEET          
  var invoiceLogSheet = ss.getSheetByName("information"); 
  
  
  //GET LAST ROW OF INVOICE LOG SHEET
  var nextRowInvoice = invoiceLogSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  
  
  
  // new code
  //POPULATE INVOICE LOG
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(invoiceLogSheet.getRange('B:B').getValues().filter(String).length +1, 2).setValue(invoice_number);
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(invoiceLogSheet.getRange('C:C').getValues().filter(String).length +1, 3).setValue(part);  
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(invoiceLogSheet.getRange('D:D').getValues().filter(String).length +1, 4).setValue(due_date);
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(invoiceLogSheet.getRange('E:E').getValues().filter(String).length +1, 5).setValue(totalInvoice);
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(invoiceLogSheet.getRange('F:F').getValues().filter(String).length +1, 6).setValue(payable_to);
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(invoiceLogSheet.getRange('G:G').getValues().filter(String).length +1, 7).setValue(project_name);
  invoiceLogSheet.getRange(invoiceLogSheet.getRange('H:H').getValues().filter(String).length +1, 8).setValue(note);


}
```